# Sets with same Cardinality, but no Explicit Bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, cardinals

Are there any good examples of sets where we know that they have the same cardinality, but have not found any explicit bijection between them?

Comment: What does "explicit" mean here?

Comment: @Burak: I would interpret that as "Not using AC, or LEM, or any other fun stuff like that" i.e. constructive.

Comment: @Kevin: Howmuch AC are we talking about? If you are not allowed to use any AC, then you can't even prove that $\{\alpha \in ON: \alpha \approx \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\ \wedge\ \forall \beta < \alpha\ \beta \not\approx  \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\}$ has the same cardinality as $\{0\}$.

Comment: Re Burak's comment. That is because without AC we cannot prove or disprove that  $\exists \alpha \in ON : \alpha \approx P(n)$. Another problem I have with Q's like this is knowing what the proposer means by "explicitly".

Answer (score 8):

The real numbers have the same cardinality as the elements of a basis of the real numbers regarded as a vector space over the rationals. The existence of such a basis needs some appropriate form of the axiom of choice, so the basis cannot be given explicitly, let alone any bijection.

Answer (score 6):

We do not know a bijection between $\omega_1$ (the first uncountable ordinal) and $\Bbb R$. While the existence of $\omega_1$ does not require the Axiom of Choice (in contrast to *Mark Bennett*'s example), the existence of a bijection requires the Continuum Hypothesis and an explicit bijection would amount to an explicit well-ordering of $\Bbb R$.

If you don't like CH, just take a correspondingly larger ordinal, you would still need to well-order $\Bbb R$ to get a bijection.

Comment: Well Oook :) Because whether there is such a bijection or not is undecidable.

Comment: @BrianO I wanted to drop AoC only for constructing the set, not for the existence of the bijection.

Comment: He wants one where we know a bijection exists. I'm not sure this counts.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thinking about it some more, my example is not "better" than Mark's insofar as in the end it only states *there exists* an ordinal that can be bijected to $\Bbb R$ and that ordinal "cannot be given explicitly, let alone any bijection". - Too bad, I first thought I had gotten rid of the indeterminacy of (one of) the sets involved ...

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Yes: an "explicit bijection" between $\mathbb{R}$ and any ordinal gives an explicit well-ordering (wo) of $\mathbb{R}$. Existence (or lack thereof) of large cardinals places lower bounds on the possible complexity of the definition (of the bijection thus of the wo).
In any case a wellordering of the reals *can't* be analytic i.e. $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1$, so it can't be arithmetic or hyperarithmetic $\Delta^1_1$. If $V = L$ there is a $\mathbf{\Delta}^1_2$ wo; if a measurable cardinal exists then there is a $\mathbf{\Delta}^1_3$ wo but no $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_2$ wo. Etc.

Comment: In any case we know that there is a bijection between $\omega_1$ and a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. But we can't even say if that subset can be $\mathbb{R}$ itself or has to be a proper subset; and there's little to be said about the bijection.

Comment: @BrianO And that's assuming choice. Without it, they might be incomparable.

Comment: @Akiva Weinberger Indeed. Incomparable, or much smaller (AD).

Answer (score 2):

The family of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$: 
$$
|\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})| = |\mathbb{R}|.
$$
But there is no way to construct an "explicit" bijection.

---

Also I was thinking of continuous functions, but it is "easy" to construct an injection $C(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ in this case, so not so interesting.

Comment: In what sense is there "no" way to construct a bijection?  Given the notion of Borel codes, it seems like one might be able to manage this somehow.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I am not very good at descriptive set theory, but I always thought that the Borel codes are not that explicit.

Comment: I'm no expert either. But it does seem like a Borel code rather explicitly identifies a Borel set. The harder part would be going the other way: for each Borel set choose a "canonical" Borel code.

Answer (score 1):

If two sets of the same size are given explicitly and "constructively", then generally someone can find and/or has found an explicit bijection. But many sets are not so-defined: we may know that such a set must exist, and we may be able to state its cardinality, but without being able to provide much more detail.

For example, the Vitali set: a continuum-sized non-measurable set of reals "defined" using the Axiom of Choice (AC). (The Vitali set is a set of representatives of the equivalence relation on the reals: $x \sim y \iff x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$.) The set is guaranteed to exist by AC, but it's just one of many possible sets of representatives of $\sim$. We know that there's a bijection between this set and $\mathbb{R}$, but we know too little about the set to say much more.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't require the sets to be explicitly given one could show that there exists subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb N$ such that there exists no explicit bijection.

If a injection is explicit it has to be possible to describe the injection and a description of the function is a finite string of symbols. By this fact these are only countable. The same is true for their images $\phi(\mathbb N)$.

But $\{x\in2^\mathbb N: |x|=\mathbb N\}$ is non-countable so there exists an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ such that it is not the image of any of the explicit injections.

Answer (score -2):

The set of transcendental numbers, set of irrational numbers and the set of real numbers are all uncountable and have the same cardinality. It is not clear (at least to me) how to *construct* a bijections among them.

The set of rational numbers  and the set of algebraic numbers are both infinite countable sets. Here also it is not clear how to construct a bijection.

Comment: If pi\*x is irrational, map x to pi\*x.  Otherwise, x/pi is irrational; map x to x/pi.  I *think* that's at least injective.

Comment: I think it is always easy to construct injective functions, even both ways. Then we have to appeal to Shrauder -Bernstein, but not sure that will be considered *constructive*.

Comment: I think that should also be surjective, since every irrational number can be expressed as pi or 1/pi times a real.  That would make it a bijection.

Comment: Let me me illustrate  with an injection from set of polynomials with integer coefficients to positive integers: Write out the polynomial in LaTeX code using the 14 symbols of the set { 0,1,2,...9, +, -, ^, x}. Read this as a base 14 number and get a positive integer. This is an injection.

Comment: I know that.  Suppose f(x) = f(y).  Then case 1: pi\*x is irrational so pi\*x = f(y).  Case 1.1: pi\*y is irrational, f(y) = pi\*y and x=y.  Case 1.2, pi\*y is rational so pi^3\*x = pi\*y; LHS is irrational while RHS is rational, contradiction.  Case 2: pi\*x is rational so x/pi = f(y).  Case 2.1: pi\*y is irrational, f(y) = y/pi and x=y.  Case 2.2: pi\*y is rational, so x = pi\*y; LHS is irrational and RHS is rational, contradiction.  Since x=y, f(x) is injective and as I already explained, surjective, making it a bijection.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That makes it clear. I learnt something today  that I should have learnt decades back.